# don't show confirmation message what is wrong in code?

Tags: javascript, laravel

js function:

```
$("#delCat").click(function(){
    //alert("test");
    if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete this category ?')){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

delete div:

```
<a id="delCat" href="delete-category/{{ $category->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: What you are trying to ask??

Comment: Post your HTML too.

Comment: <a id="delCat" href="delete-category/{{ $category->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

Disable default behaviour of link:

```
$("#delCat").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //alert("test");
  if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete this category ?')){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false
  }
});
```

Or directly attached to link:

```
<a id="delCat" href="delete-category/{{ $category->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</a>
```

Comment: hi , its directly delete my category no ask cofirmation message

Comment: you used which solution? 1st or 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#delCat').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm('Are you sure ... ?')){
    return true; 
  } 
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="delCat" href='link_to_delete'  class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
```

I have no enough knowledge about jquery but I guess, you should prevent default behaviour from event target.